# Upload Imagesize

Tags: android

In my `ProfileFargment.java` I'm creating the user's profile. Right now it has a profile pic (which comes from the user's Google profile pic) and a banner picture. I've made a button which basically allows the user to change its banner picture but only some images are able to be loaded. I don't know if this has something to do with the size of the images or not... This is the code that I use:

**Button**

```
 btnEditarFotoCapa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openGallery(); // Chama a função para abrir a galeria
        }
    });
```

**Intent**

```
private void openGallery(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGES);
}
```

**Retrieve gallery image**

```
// Caso a galeria tenha sido aberta, aplica a imagem na foto de capa
//
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGES){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        ImageView imgFotoCapa = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgFotoCapa);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).resize(446, 203).into(imgFotoCapa);

        /* SharedPreferences myPrefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("FotoCapa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefsEdit = myPrefs.edit();
        myPrefsEdit.putString("fotoCapa", imageUri.toString());
        myPrefsEdit.commit(); */
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 1) Rather than resizing, try keeping same width / height as received image, see if Picasso able to handle .....Option 2) Try out with https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library rather than Picasso

Comment: I'll try glide. Btw, is it a good or a bad practice have two libraries like, for example, Picasso and Glide in the same project?  Because I've used Picasso in a lot of situations, do I need to replace everything with glide?

Comment: Go through this , You may get a good conclusion https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d

Comment: Hm, so Glide is better in a lot of situations. Probably I'm gonna change from Picasso to Glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently used **Picasso** library like you and i had a similar problem. The reason why some images aren't loaded it's due to they're size. Picasso have some problems with the download of big images because of some cache problems.

Here an exemple of this issue
[GitHub Picasso Large Image Issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/526)

ImageRequest example

```
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(link, new 
    Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    setBackground(context,bitmap);
                }
            }, 0, 0, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VolleyImage",error.toString());
                }
            });
    rq.add(request);
```

Comment: Uh, that explains a lot... Should I use another library?

Comment: Even if it seems to be deprecated, i solved the problem using Imagerequest. I add an example on the post

Answer (score 1):

Try to this code ..

used Glide to load image it is easy and latest.

add glide dependecy into app level gradle file..

```
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

after below code is open gallery

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

get path of select image..

```
    /**
 * this method used to get camera image path.
 *
 * @param
 * @return
 */

public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

after that onActivity Result method..

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String path = getPathFromURI(uri);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(path)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                    .into(epfIvUserImage);
        } 
}
```

Comment: The `REQUEST_GALLERY` is giving me an error: Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob in android. Do I need to create a class with that name?

Comment: protected int REQUEST_GALLERY = 1;

Comment: Sweet, thanks!. Now what is giving me the last error is `apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())`. It says cannot resolve method apply

Comment: in my case it working if is not working then remove it. but i think import problem. it show only rounded image.

Comment: Well, I've tested and it doesn't display any image at all ahah

Comment: post your code for gallery open and select image show into glide.

Comment: The rest of the code I have exactly like you:

  `   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            ImageView imgFotoCapa = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgFotoCapa);
            String path = getPathFromURI(uri);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(path)
                    .into(imgFotoCapa);
        }
    }`

Comment: check debug point if going inside if condition. and also if your image is large then take few time to load.

Comment: I've checked. It is doing everything OK, no errors. When comes to the part of loading the image to Glide, my ImageView gets insivible

Comment: I don't know if this has something do to with it but, my `findViewById` says that may cause a `java.lang.NullException`

Comment: it means imageview not  define.

Comment: ImageView imgFotoCapa = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgFotoCapa);
        this line define as ImageView imagview as class level after that in oncrateView() method defin imageview=findviewbyid.

Comment: ImageView imgFotoCapa = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgFotoCapa);
        this line remove from onActivityResult method.

Comment: And I put that line in onCreateView?

Comment: yes but imageview object it class level then it can access any where into class.

Comment: How do I make it class level so it can be accessed in other classes? I've already put that line in onCreateView

Comment: i hope you know how to define variable as class level.

Comment: Actually, I don't ahah

Comment: I've figured it out but now my app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso Transformation

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).transform(new ImageTransformation()).placeholder(placeHolder).error(placeHolder).into(imageView);


public class ImageTransformation implements Transformation {
    @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int targetWidth = 256;
        double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
        int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, true);
        if (result != source) {
            // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
            source.recycle();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override public String key() {
        return "cropPosterTransformation" + 256;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your activity's `onActivityResult`, call `super.onActivityResult()`. Usually, the fragment can get a catch to result only if you make your activity override `onActivityResult` and call its `super`.